# Type of scan used in this program

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, port-scanning

I came across a relatively simple java code while trying to design a Tcp PortScanner. The following code checks for the listening ports available on the local machine.
I wonder what kind of scan it uses to check its status, i mean is it using Tcp Syn scan , or Tcp connect scan or anything other than this. I'm grateful for your response.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

class PortScanner {
   public static void main(String []args) {
      for (int port = 1; port <= 65535; port++) {
         try {
           Socket socket = new Socket();
           socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port), 1000);
           socket.close();
           System.out.println("Port " + port + " is open");
         } catch (Exception ex) {
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: All it's doing is trying to connect to the IP and port. If no TCP handshake is made, an error code is returned or an exception is thrown. Any time a handshake is completed (the `connect` and `close` calls succeed) - it writes that port is open.

Comment: A SYN *is* a connect. Your question doesn't make sense.